# Velodyne VLP16 RAW data to Rosbag conversion Error -2

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, vlp16, vlp-16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to convert a raw Velodyne VLP16 .pcap file to Rosbag but I am getting stuck in the first step. Basically, I run the following command:

$ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch pcap:=$(pwd)/velodyne_lidar.pcap readonce:=true

Then when I try to see the published information at /velodyne_points "rostopic echo /velodyne_points" is not printing anything. I am getting the following warning --> Error -2 reading Velodyne packet

[image: Picture]

Has anyone ever experienced this issue? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387124/velodyne-vlp16-raw-data-to-rosbag-conversion-error--2/) by [risc-v](https://answers.ros.org/users/85330/risc-v/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-23**:
If you try this command using your own filename, do you see any messages on /scan?

```
rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _pcap:=dump.pcap
```

Note: this is rosrun, not roslaunch, so the underscore in front of pcap indicates it's a private parameter, not a topic name remap.

**Comment by [risc-v](https://answers.ros.org/users/85330/risc-v/) on 2021-09-23**:
Hi Mike,

Thanks very much for your reply. I tried the command you suggested but I am still getting the same error --> [ WARN] [1632399476.053965374]: Error -2 reading Velodyne packet.

I tried other .pcap files from the internet and they work perfectly meaning that I see data output on /velodyne_points. I tried to filter packets on the .pcap files giving me the -2 error (I used Wireshark for that, mainly keeping UDP packets), but still not working and giving the same error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-23**:
Sounds like it is that specific pcap file. In wireshark, I would check the destination port number in the udp header. I believe the driver expects it to be 2368. If your file has something different, you have to specify it on the command line.

**Comment by [risc-v](https://answers.ros.org/users/85330/risc-v/) on 2021-09-24**:
Hi Mike,

That worked perfectly Thanks very much. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like this problem is specific to one pcap file. In wireshark, I would check the destination port number in the udp header. I believe the driver expects it to be 2368. If your file has something different, you have to specify it on the command line.

I guess we now know that -2 means "no data packets found".

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [risc-v](https://answers.ros.org/users/85330/risc-v/) on 2021-09-24**:
Hi Mike,

That's great. Changing the port number on the command line worked like a charm. All packets are visible now. Thanks again. Really appreciate it :)